# Django - Questions around how to validate current environment and how to run in production

Tags: python, django, apache

my apologies, for what might be a rather simple and amateur set of questions.

I recently was voluntold (more like told) to absorb a django/python project that was developed by someone else. That someone else has left, and now I have to pick this up and run with it as there is no other backup.

Being a university student (intern at work for another 12 mos), I don't think this experience will go to waste AT ALL so I'm happy to be involved, but because this is production and in use today I need to ramp up rather quickly.

*// sordid_tale*

I am new to Python, Django, Anaconda, PostGreSQL and the world. I know some coding from my first two years, and I've been reading through books to get up to speed.

**Current scenario:**

- Project deployed in production server (windows 2012)
- project has an open connection to postgresql and publishes a website used by multiple people across the firm to upload math analytics for reporting.
- i started the project up using the `python manage.py runserver 123.123.22.22:8000` which started the DEVELOPMENT server and sent me a big ol' warning sign saying don't do this in production.
- so i took it down lol. Now trying to figure out how to run in production.
- looks like `gunicorn` and `uwsgi` are two ways to start the production environment once deployment is complete.
- but then I searched on the server folders for gunicorn, uwsgi but got no returns. Running gunicorn and uwsgi returns command is not recognized.
- I cannot find any `*.wsgi` files within the server
- Also noted there might be an `APACHE` dependency, but I couldn't find any apache files in program files.

Q) With above info - is it fair to say the developer never really "promoted" the code to production and was just using the runserver command to get things going on prod server?

Q) Users on their own desktops try to browse to 123.123.22.22 to access site - but they get an error. But browsing to 123.123.22.22:8000 gets them to the site. I read that for HTTP, you need to have a port 80 defined when running server. So `python manage.py runserver 123.123.22.22:80`. But this gives me an error I don't have privs to run this. To rectify I opened command prompt in Admin mode, but still got the same error. Any assistance?

Once again sincere apologies if the questions are too basic. I am trying to learn a new coding language, but also having to manage the existing prod environment for business continuity, while also trying to get Python, Anaconda, PostGres setup on my local machine for testing and training.

**Many thanks!**

Comment: **Q1)** No, you can't know that for sure just looking at the code repositories. What if the previous developer SSH'd into the server to start it? (bad practice, but known to happen).
**Q2)** In linux based systems (and looks like in Windows as well?) only Admin users can bind to (open) ports < 1024. That's why running a prod server is actually complex (and where the WSGI kicks in: You have a server capable of binding to port 80, such as apache, and with WSGI you pass the requests that come to it to a server running in a non privileged mode)

Comment: i see. thank you for such a quick response! If the user SSH'ed into the server, any way for me to replicate this? I only have the prod server to play with and don't have any other access to files. Seems like Q2 is related to Q1, if I find the WSGI method to kick in this would solve for Q2. Then I'm stuck on how to replicate this...any suggestions?

Comment: sorry to be following up my earlier comment. but even if dev was ssh'ing into the server, won't there be local install of apache, *.wsgi files that would be part of the project and system files that would need to be present on the deployed production server? To clarify I couldn't find anything of that sort...

Comment: If the previous developer left in good terms, I'd ask him. Really!! Also, to replicate complex environments in your laptop you can take a look to Docker and Docker-compose. Also, investigate how to create backups of your production data. And ask yourself: How important is that server? Are users using it as of now? Having `:8000` in a URL seems to indicate that the server is not really used?

Comment: *won't there be local install of apache, \*.wsgi files*. There should... But I also should quit smoking and here I am **:D** Can you SSH into the prod server yourself?

Comment: Wait, wait... when you say *I started the project up* you mean in the actual server or locally (in your laptop, to say so?) because if it's the former, and there are not wsgi files or other trace of the project in the production server, I guess you can lean towards it never been run? (at least not "seriously"?)

Comment: @ prev dev deffo didn't leave in good terms to ask for help.

Comment: also - sorry when i said started up project. I meant I logged into the production server, then through cmd prompt, wrote in python manage.py runserver X.x.x.x:8000 for the app to start on the server. This was not on my desktop. There is a WSGI file which is under the project name - WSGI.PY i believe. But no Gunicorn that I can see. I am not how, or what benefit, it would be for me to SSH into the machine given I already have access to the production server - unless I misunderstood your question. THANKS AGAIN BTW

Comment: yeah, yeah... sorry... I meant to know in what machine the `runserver ...:8000` was run. *logged into the production server* answers the question. Also, you say that that the server *publishes a website used by multiple people*. So the people in the company are using it? Because that'd mean **something** is up and running, no?